# Javascript variables & scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Javascript and Angular and am a bit confused as to how the below code is executing:

```
angular.controller('TestController',function($scope){
    $scope.counter = {clicks:0};
    $scope.count = function(){
        $scope.clicks += 1;
    }
});
```

I am able to write $scope.clicks += 1 and the count increases correctly by 1. Isn't counter a Javascript object and dont we have to write it as $scope.counter.clicks += 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. It **IS** a javascript object and you should be writing `$scope.counter.clicks += 1` if this is the variable you want to increment.

I assume you are binding with `{{clicks}}` and therefore you **think** it is working correctly, but it isn't (this is a different property on the scope). You should be binding `{{counter.clicks}}` to see the "real" value.

You can write a `console.log` line inside the count() function to see the true value of `$scope.counter.clicks` and check for yourself.

Comment: You are right. I had to bind $scope.counter.clicks with {{counter.clicks}} to actually see it working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Scope is the area in which your functions are executing. Json is a different language than JavaScript and angular is a js framework. You are simply counting a click. Your code is working properly.

Comment: @Oriol he originally stated json in his question please un down arrow thanks